# may be NSURLSession or NSMutableURLRequest does not release memory calling through loop

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, nsurl, nsmutableurlrequest

My Problem :- NSURLSession does not release previous call API Memory of 5MB Chunk

I am calling APIs in do while loop to upload 500MB video. I have to send every 5MB chunk with different APIs not in one API.

For Example 500MB Video and create 100 chunks and send using NSURLSession so calls 100 times but NSURLSession does not release previous call API Memory of 5MB Chunk

(1) I have created 5MB Chunk.

(2) read File using NSFileHandle with 5MB Chunk using OffSet

(3) change URL for all chunk and call api (necessary to send all chunk at different URL)

I do not want convert video in NSData in (500MB) i want to send chunk through API

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        //dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

        __block NSUInteger counterFailure = 0; // PSM Anks calling blob by url fails 4 time, exit for funtion

        arrBlobIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        __block NSInteger intBlockIdCount = 100000; // PSM Anks blobid to assign id to every blob
        __block NSUInteger offset = 0; // PSM Anks offset to start posution to read data

        NSUInteger length = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[urlOfGallaryVideo path] error:nil] fileSize]; // PSM anks total lenght of media
        NSUInteger intChunkSize = (5000 * 1024); // PSM anks chunk size

            while (offset < length){

                //dispatch_group_enter(group);

                NSLog(@"offset 1 : %lu",(unsigned long)offset);

                // PSM Anks Creat Chunk from file according to length

                NSUInteger intThisChunkSize = length - offset > intChunkSize ? intChunkSize : length - offset;
                //NSData* chunk = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(char *)[myBlob bytes] + offset length:intThisChunkSize freeWhenDone:NO];

                __block NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:[urlOfGallaryVideo path]];
                [fileHandle seekToFileOffset:offset];
                __block NSData *dataChunk = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:intThisChunkSize];

                // PSM Anks Convert block id in Base 64 encode

                NSData *dataBlockId = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",intBlockIdCount] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSString *base64BlockId = [dataBlockId base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&comp=block&blockid=%@",[dictAzureSAS objectForKey:@"uri"],base64BlockId]]];

                [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
                [request setHTTPBody:dataChunk];
                //[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)dataChunk.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; // Do not need
                //[request setValue:strVideoMIMEType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; // Do not need
                [request addValue:@"BlockBlob" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-ms-blob-type"];

                //NSLog(@"request : %@",request);
                //NSLog(@"dataChunk.length : %lu \n url for blob %@ \n request %@",(unsigned long)dataChunk.length,[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&comp=block&blockid=%@",[dictAzureSAS objectForKey:@"uri"],base64BlockId]],request);

                NSLog(@"dataChunk.length : %lu",(unsigned long)dataChunk.length);

                NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
                config.URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
                config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20.0;
                config.URLCredentialStorage = nil;
                config.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
                ///NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
                config = nil;

                //NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
                NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];


                NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTaskForUpload = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


                    NSLog(@"Finished with status code: %li", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
                    NSLog(@"response: %@", response);
                    NSLog(@"error: %@ %@", error,error.description);

                    if(data != nil) // PSM anks Check Data is nil otherwise app crashed
                    {
                        NSMutableArray *jsonList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                        NSLog(@"jsonList: %@", jsonList);
                    }

                    dataChunk = nil;
                    fileHandle = nil;
                    if(error == nil)
                    {
                        /*
                        // PSM Anks First Add Then increment
                        [arrBlobIds addObject:base64BlockId];
                        intBlockIdCount++;
                        offset += intThisChunkSize;

                        counterFailure = 0;
                        */

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /*
                        counterFailure++;
                        offset = intThisChunkSize;

                        if(counterFailure >= 4)
                        {

                            NSLog(@"Enter counter Failure %lu",(unsigned long)counterFailure);
                            counterFailure = 0;
                            [self stopLoader];
                            [CommonAlertViewMsgs cannotConnectServer:self];
                            return ;
                        }
                        */
                    }
                    //dispatch_group_leave(group);
                    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                    [session finishTasksAndInvalidate];

                }];


                [dataTaskForUpload resume];
                dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


                NSLog(@"offset 2 : %lu",(unsigned long)offset);
            }
```

Comment: In addition to Charles' answer below, re `@autoreleasepool`, I would advise against creating a new `NSURLSession` for each request.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for reply
you want to say split 500MB files in 5MB files means I want to create 100 FIles of 5MB. then after upload one by one

Comment: @Rob
 I would advise against creating a new NSURLSession for each request. 
in do while loop NSURLSession create new one for every request am i right?

Comment: No, I'm saying the exact opposite. Do _not_ create a new `NSURLSession` in your `while` loop. Create it _before_ the loop (perhaps saving it in some property of your class), and simply use it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably that your `NSData` objects are being put in an autorelease pool, which is never getting drained until after your main `dispatch_async` block completes. You can probably fix the immediate problem by adding an `@autoreleasepool` to your while loop; i.e.

```
while (offset < length) @autoreleasepool {
```

However, your `dispatch_semaphore_wait` at the end is blocking a dispatch queue, which is generally discouraged. What I would recommend would be, in addition to adding the `@autoreleaspool` to the while loop, to use a dispatch group instead of the semaphore, and to use `dispatch_group_notify` at the end instead of `dispatch_group_wait`. This will cause your main `dispatch_async` block to complete, which will release any autoreleased objects which have accumulated in it, and then the block you pass to `dispatch_group_notify` will be called once all your operations are complete.

EDIT: Knowing a little more about what you're trying to do, here is an alternative that will run the processes one at a time, while still not blocking the dispatch queue:

(pseudocode)

```
- (void)sendRequestWithOffset:length:otherParameters: {
    send the url request {
        do what you do

        if newOffset < length {
            [self sendRequestWithOffset:newOffset length:length otherParameters:whatever];
        } else {
            hooray, we're done
        }
    }
}
```

It's sort of like a recursive call (but not really, since we won't accumulate stack frames). Basically it's an asyncronous version of your while loop; your tasks occur one at a time, there's no blockage of dispatch queues, and since each dispatch queue has its own autorelease pool, you won't get buildup of autoreleased objects either and your memory usage should stay reasonable.

Comment: Well, there are multiple ways of designing it. If a consecutive process is what you need, you can do that without blocking a dispatch queue as well; just execute step A, then call step B in the completion handler, etc. For this example, you could make a method taking the file handle as an argument, and then just call the method again if you're not done yet.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka 
Thanks for response
I think we can not use `@autoreleasepool` in ARC I am using Xcode 9.
am i Right? Yes I got it You recommended dispatch_group_wait 
Thanks once again for prompt response but how can i use `@autoreleasepool` in ARC

Comment: @Rob 
Thanks for reponse
Ya I can replace dispatch_semaphore_wait to dispatch_group_notify. I already comment code of dispatch_group_notify.
Which one is better dispatch_semaphore_wait or dispatch_group_notify.
for fast prcessing?

Comment: @Rob I want run one request at that time so there is only one concurrent requests after getting first request. I call another request.
->I got it file based upload means if video is 500MB then create 100files with 5MB size and then send one by one using file upload
but ROB I have to set (necessary) content type  according to server requirements

Comment: @AnkurPatel If you want to just run one request at a time, here's what I'd do: 1) get rid of the while loop, and move its contents into a separate method that takes the file handle and the number of remaining bytes as arguments. 2) In NSURLDataTask's completion handler, subtract the appropriate amount from the remaining bytes, check whether it's zero, and call the method again if it's not. That's probably the most performant way you're going to run the tasks one at a time, since you won't be blocking up any dispatch queues, and any autoreleased memory will be quickly dealt with.

Comment: @Rob Charles my code for dispatch_semaphore_wait 
is correct ?
I will take care about use dispatch_group_notify at the end instead of dispatch_group_wait

Comment: @AnkurPatel Sorry, I'm not parsing that sentence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158098/discussion-between-ankur-patel-and-charles-srstka).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minimize your memory footprint while the uploads run, you should:

- Try `@autoreleasepool` as advised by [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47079416/1271826);
- Reuse one `NSURLSession` rather than recreating a new `NSURLSession` each time inside your loop; and
- Use file-based upload tasks (e.g. [`uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1411550-uploadtaskwithrequest?language=objc)) rather than `dataTask`.

Note, with file-based upload tasks, you can still configure your `NSURLRequest` like you are now, but don't set `httpBody`, but instead supply that as the `fromFile` parameter of the above method.

Once you have this memory issue behind you, you can pursue other approaches to improve performance, too, but let's not get ahead of ourselves.